# How do I access the label after the aTag href to get the name of a product listed on a website?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

Whenever I run my code and try to print the item title, which is the aTag label, it prints out "none". I want to access the paragraph that comes after the href and before the closing aTag.

```
    import bs4
    #uReq is our arbitrary shorthand for urllib.request
    import urllib
    from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

    #The URL we plan to use
    my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/'

    #uReq(my_url) opens up web client
    Client = uReq(my_url)
    #uClient.read dumps everything out of the url
    html_page = Client.read()
    Client.close()


    page_soup = soup(html_page, "html.parser")
    itemContainers= page_soup.findAll("div{"class":"item-container"})
    page = page_soup.find("h2","swiper-box-top-title")
    itemTitle = itemContainers[0].find("class", "item-title")
    print(itemTitle)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(my_url).text, "html5lib")
links = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "item-title"})
for link in links:
    print(link.text)
    print(link["href"])
```

---

```
Acer KG271 bmiix 27" Full HD 1920 x 1080 75Hz 1ms HDMI VGA AMD FreeSync ZeroFrame Flikcer-Less BlueShield Built-in Speakers ...
https://www.newegg.com/black-acer-kg1-series-kg271-bmiix-27/p/N82E16824011127?Item=N82E16824011127&cm_sp=Homepage_SS-_-P1_24-011-127-_-04302020
HP S700 2.5" 1TB SATA III 3D TLC Internal Solid State Drive (SSD) 6MC15AA#ABC
https://www.newegg.com/hp-s700-1tb/p/0D9-000H-007T9?Item=0D9-000H-007T9&cm_sp=Homepage_SS-_-P2_0D9-000H-007T9-_-04302020
```

---

PS: NewEgg uses google ReCaptcha and you'll most certainly be blocked after a couple of requests.